# How is this factoring done?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you go from:

$f'(x)$ = $9x(x-9)^{8}$+$(x-9)^{9} = 0$

to:

$f'(x)$ = $(x-9)^{8} (10x-9) = 0$?

Comment: Take a factor of $(x-9)^8$ out of both terms. You should get $(x-9)^8(9x+(x-9))=(x-9)^8(10x-9)$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that:
$$
9x(x-9)^8+(x-9)^9=9x(x-9)^8+(x-9)(x-9)^8=\\
(9x+(x-9))(x-9)^8=(10x-9)(x-9)^8
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x-9)^8=A(x)$

then

$$9x(x-9)^{8}+(x-9)^{9}=9x\cdot A(x)+(x-9)\cdot A(x)=$$

$$=A(x)\cdot (9x+(x-9)=A(x)\cdot (10x-9)$$

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by $(x-9)^8$, you get the quotient $9x+(x-9)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$(x-9)^8(9x+x-9)=0$$ you can check this by multiplying out
$$9x(x-9)^8+(x-9)^9=0$$